# CSS - Force a child DIV to expand page width?

Tags: css

I am working on an editable navigation. The user can add many tabs across the top as they wish. In the event that there are many tabs that would force the set of tabs to be broken/wrapped to the next line, I would like to force it on 1 line even if this means that the page width would grow immensely.

Is there a way for a child DIV to expand a page width even if the content is in a wrapper? In my JS Fiddle link below, I have a simple wrapper page with a right sidenav. I am using Listamatic tabs (http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal05.htm) for the top. As you can see, the tabs are breaking into many rows of tabs and it doesn't look great. Can I use some CSS to force the DIV to not wrap onto a 2nd or 3rd line? I would like the DIV to be liquid based on the number of tabs (and length of the text in the tab text). Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/yUPCC/3/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to expand a child past it's parent is to use an absolute width. If you do something like that, you'll have z-index issues to sort. You could do something like make the tab list scroll within its div.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yUPCC/4/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `white-space: nowrap` on the body and `display: inline-block` on the columns. `vertical-align: top` may also be required on some columns.

Here's a working demo. I tried to remove everything that wasn't needed to just illustrate the concept.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/xauMb/

CSS:

```
body {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#container {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.column {
    display: inline-block;
}

.rightnav {
    white-space: normal;
}
```